# Having a background color activated WHILE taking a photo - Android Studio

Tags: android, ios

I'm trying to make an app as part of a project of mine where I need to illuminate the object I'm taking a picture of (front camera) with different colours, provided by the screen itself. I'm new to android programming and so far have only been able to access the camera (the one in the back, since from my research it is not possible through intent to access the one in the front automatically), take a picture of it and show it.

While taking a picture I need different colours illuminating it. I've heard that this is possible in iOS with some versions of snapchat, which creates a "simulated" flash, illuminating the front screen in white. How could I manipulate this to get other colours?

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

It is actually pretty simple and just makes me feel like a fool and realize how little I know about java and android development overall :D

I was able to do this by applying a surfaceView to the full screen, so it's a simple XML

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/btn_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- Background changed on the surfaceview so far-->
        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#9AE916" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Afterwards, I just access the camera and use the volume up button to change the colours. So far, it is hardcoded

```js
public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    Camera camera;

    @InjectView(R.id.surfaceView)
    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    Camera.PictureCallback jpegCallback;
    Camera.ShutterCallback shutterCallback;
    public int color_flag = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.camera_activity);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);
        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);



        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        //Install a surfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the underlying surface is created and destroyed
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        //deprecated setting, but required on android versions prior to 3.0
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        //Sets brightness to max value
        WindowManager.LayoutParams layout = getWindow().getAttributes();
        layout.screenBrightness = 1;
        getWindow().setAttributes(layout);

        jpegCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

                //TODO takes care of rotation ------------------------------------------------------
                if(data != null){
                    int screenWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
                    int screenHeight = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
                    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, (data != null) ? data.length : 0);
                    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                        // Notice that width and height are reversed
                        Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, screenHeight, screenWidth, true);
                        int w = scaled.getWidth();
                        int h = scaled.getHeight();
                        // Setting post rotate to 90
                        Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
                        mtx.postRotate(90);
                        // Rotating Bitmap
                        bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaled, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, true);
                    }else{// LANDSCAPE MODE
                        //No need to reverse width and height
                        Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, screenWidth,screenHeight , true);
                        bm=scaled;
                    }

                }

                //TODO assign bitmap to be saved----------------------------------------------------

                FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
                File file_image= getDirc();
                if (!file_image.exists() && !file_image.mkdirs()){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Can't create directory to save",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss");
                String date = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
                String photofile = "SP_Interface" +date+".jpg";
                String file_name = file_image.getAbsolutePath()+ "/" + photofile;
                File picfile = new File(file_name);
                try{
                    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(picfile);
                    outputStream.write(data);
                    outputStream.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                } finally {

                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Picture saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                refreshCamera();
                refreshGallery(picfile);
            }
        };

    }

    private void refreshGallery(File file){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    public void refreshCamera(){
        if(surfaceHolder.getSurface()==null){
            //preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }
        //stop preview before making changes
        try {
            camera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        //set preview size and make any resize, rotate or reformatting changes here. Start preview with new settings
        try{
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();
        }catch (Exception e){}
    }

    private File getDirc(){
        File dics = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
        return new File(dics,"SP_Interface");
    }

    public void cameraImage(){
        //take the picture
        camera.takePicture(null,null,jpegCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        //open the FRONT camera
        try {
            camera = Camera.open(1);
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {

        }

        Camera.Parameters parameters;
        parameters = camera.getParameters();
        //modify parameter
        parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(20);
        parameters.setPreviewSize(352,288);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        try{
            //The surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();
        }catch(Exception e){}

    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        refreshCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        //stop preview and release the camera
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera=null;
    }

    //Volume up changes to next color
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP)
        {
            switch (color_flag){
                case 0:
                    color_flag+=1;

                    surfaceView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0000FF"));

                    break;
                case 1:
                    color_flag+=1;

                    surfaceView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FFFF"));

                    break;
                case 2:
                    color_flag+=1;

                    surfaceView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF00FF"));

                    break;
                case 3:
                    color_flag+=1;

                    surfaceView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));

                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    //Volume down takes the picture
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)
        {
            camera.takePicture(null,null,jpegCallback);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Hope it helps someone!

TIP: Study layouts more, after you understand how they work there's a lot you can do